# Sum of non uniformly continuous and uniformly continuous is non uniformly continuous?

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

I have this question:

> Prove/disprove: $f(x)=x\ln x+\sin(x^3)\frac1x$ is uniformly continuous in $(0,\infty)$.

I know that $\sin(x^3)\frac1x$ is uniformly continuous and $x\ln x$ is non uniformly continuous. I tried proving that the sum of uniformly continuous function and non uniformly continuous function is non uniformly continuous, but is this even true?

Comment: Yes, just prove it by contradiction.

Comment: "uc + nuc giving uc" would be contradictory, because it would be equivalent to "uc - uc is nuc" (though for every $\epsilon$ you could find $\delta$ independent of $x$ such that...).

Answer (score 2):

The sum of two uniform continuous maps $f,g$ is uniformly continuous.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous and $g$ is not, $f+g$ can't be uniformly continuous as otherwise $g = (f+g) - f$ would be uniformly continuous.

Comment: I suspect this would be even clearer if you said "so the difference is also  uniformly continuous" or had had $g=(f+g)+(-g)$

Comment: thank you! got it.